# Next JS Image, I cant make the image position to center using tailwind

Tags: reactjs, next.js, centering, tailwind-css, nextjs-image

Hi Im working on a project using next js and tailwind css. I want to center this image but next js seems to ignore flex and justify-center as shown on the image. [image]

I want to dynamically pass positions to the (ex. justify-start, justify-end).
Any help is appreciated.

```
import NextImage from '@components/image-copy'

function test() {

  return (
    <div className="w-full bg-red-400">
      <NextImage
        src="/images/billboard-corner.webp"
        url={'www.facebook.com'}
        layoutFill={true}
        wrapper="h-60  w-1/2 bg-red-100 relative flex justify-center"
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default test
```

And here is my image component.

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import Image from 'next/image'

const NextImage = ({
  src,
  alt,
  className,
  linkType = 'undef',
  target,
  url,
  draggable,
  width,
  height,
  wrapper,
  position,
  layoutFill,
}) => {

  const style = `${wrapper} relative `

return (
    <>
      {layoutFill ? (
        linkType === 'link' ? (
          <div className={style}>
            <Link href={url}>
              <a>
                <Image src={src} alt={alt} layout="fill" draggable={draggable} className={className} />
              </a>
            </Link>
          </div>
        ) : (
          linkType === 'undef' && (
            <>
              <div className={style}>
                <Image src={src} alt={alt} layout="fill" draggable={draggable} className={className} />
              </div>
            </>
          )
        )
      ) : <div>Example</div>
    }
    </>
  )
}
```

export default NextImage

Answer (score 0):

Your image should be correct, since you use w-1/2 (50% of the width)

You may want to remove `w-1/2` if you don't want it to be 50%, or use `w-full`